# Generate pseudo random float number between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive) in C++/Qt5

Tags: random, floating-point, qt5

I want to generate a pseudo random number between `0.0f` (inclusive) and `1.0f` (exclusive) in **C++** using **Qt5**.

How can I do this in the recommended/Qt way?

Answer (score 1):

y can divide a random number by double(RAND_MAX) as following:

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    cout<<rand()/double(RAND_MAX)<<'\t';
}
```

Comment: Does that imply there is no Qt spesific way that relates to Qt PRNG?